# Allow me to delete my own comments if they get moved to chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, chat, deleted-comments

Normally, I can delete a comment on a post at any time after I comment.

However, if a moderator moves the post's comments to chat, I lose the ability to delete my comments that got moved to chat.

Users shouldn't be disallowed from deleting their own comments if they get moved to chat. It may not even be the user's fault, if they commented before some others started using it as extended discussions.

FYI: We had a user [complain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308973) about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* delete your own comments if they get moved to chat. Often the moderator moving them will do it for you, without you even having to ask.

...of course, you can't delete the chat messages that result from the move. That'd break the conversation and defeat the whole purpose of moving them to chat.

If you don't think anyone cares about the conversation anymore, you could flag it and ask that a moderator delete the room.

If it really bothers you, you can request that ALL chat messages associated with your profile be anonymized and your chat account deleted.

Or, if it's a short conversation, I guess you could just wait for the room to [go away on its own](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).

Comment: By the way, did you check the question I linked? The one where there was a user complaining?

Comment: Yes, he thinks chat is bad because it is permanent and searchable. I suspect he may dislike many other things about these sites once he learns that we publish regular data dumps as Bittorrent downloads.

Comment: And that comments can be searched via SEDE...

Answer (score 8):

I think that this happens too infrequently to make any changes for this. Just like you're sometimes not able to delete your own question, even if you'd like to, this is a situation were you cannot (easily) delete your own comments. Comments fall under the CC BY-SA license too.

If you need to get rid of some of your migrated comments, and have a good reason to do so, you can always flag them for moderator attention (which is different from the usual spam/offensive chat flags which are also handled by 10k users) in chat. Requests for deletion of own messages are not too uncommon and are usually granted.

Comment: We once had a user post a long rant about how he really didn't like the prospect of his comments being moved to chat, because he loses the ability to self-delete them. Presumably, he flagged his messages, but they were declined. Remember that users with 10k+ rep overall on the network can handle chat flags, not just moderators.

Comment: Ok, I see it now.  Frozen rooms are hidden by default, you you have to go find them (or follow links from the question).  I don't think 10+ users can handle chat flags - I've only ever been able to validate abuse flags (usually in Russian).  I've never seen any flags for chat message deletion.  Unless there's a secret way of doing this that I don't know, or it's a SO specific thing.

Comment: @Snow Maybe such users can only handle spam/offensive flags, and not custom flags.